Indentation Rule in SonarLint for Typescript
I am new to sonarLint rules, I am trying to findout the rule for indentation and variable naming in typescript rules.But couldn't find it.
I was able to find naming rules for classes and functions but not for variables.
Does sonarlint have indentation rule and naming convention for varibales?
Help me in figuring out this
Does SonarLint gives support for indentation in typescript or not?

Sonar has no rule for JavaScript or TypeScript regarding indentation.
You can use another tool, such as prettier, for that purpose.
